# Check if server is running from Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

I am using the following code to check if my server is running:

```js
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        function checkServerStatus() {
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.onload = function() {
                alert('success');
            };
            img.onerror = function() {
                alert('error');
            };
            img.src = 'http://127.0.0.1:12345/images/test.png';
        }
        $(checkServerStatus);
    </script>
</head>
```

When I run this code while my server is running, Chrome, FireFox and IE10 output "success" whereas MS Edge "error". How can I make Edge detect the running server like the others?

Comment: It depends on the error. Output the full error message (and not just `"error"`, which is... not very useful) using `img.onerror = function(err) {
               console.log(err);
            }` then tell us what the actual error is.

Comment: @JeremyThille - I've tried that but the param doesn't seem to contain any useful information, e.g why the image has failed to load.

Comment: err.message should be a slightly more useful piece of information. Also, the dev tools network pane should give some kind of reason or HTTP status code that should shed SOME kind of light

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Jquery. :)
Maybe try to use a library that focuses their efforts in doing XHR requests:

https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios

Comment: You're right... @jpen, why use that, instead of just `checkServerStatus()` ? Why include jQuery at all?

Comment: about:flags - turn on Allow localhost loopback (this might put your device at risk). Some custom hosts file mappings might require additional configuration. See our FAQ for more information. Close and restart Edge.